# Can't draw an arrow using polyline in GoogleMap V2

Tags: android, google-maps-android-api-2, android-maps-v2

I try to draw an arrow using a polyline as shown in the following picture.
The polyline starts at point p1, goes to p2, then to p3, back to p2 and finally to p4.
[image]
The problem is, whenever p3 is straight towards west of p2, the result is as follows:
[image]
Here is the code:

```
    PolylineOptions po = new PolylineOptions();
    LatLng p1 = new LatLng(49.4, 8.45);
    LatLng p2 = new LatLng(49.3, 8.6);
    LatLng p3 = new LatLng(49.3, 8.5);
    LatLng p4 = new LatLng(49.35, 8.6);

    po.add(p1);
    po.add(p2);
    po.add(p3);
    po.add(p2);
    po.add(p4);
    map.addPolyline(po);
```

By just exchanging the sequence from p1-p2-p3-p2-p4 into p1-p2-p4-p2-p3 I got the result of the first picture.
I guess this is a bug in GoogleMap. But I would be interested, whether it appears also on other devices than mine ( a Galaxy S2) before I file the bug.

**UPDATE**

This bug was handled in Google issue tracker

https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/35821816

It was fixed in Google Play Services - 9.2.56

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-api/releases#june_27_2016

Comment: Just found issue http://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/issues/detail?id=5313 and added my case, as I think it's much easier to reproduce, than the ones so far described. Would still be interested in whether it appears on all devices.